# How to enter search for a text and retrieve values from search results through Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriver

I am trying to extract data from the following website:
https://www.polymergenome.org/explore/index.php?m=1

Please enter 'CCOCCO' in the search box and click on "Predict Properties".  From the predicted table, I want to extract 'Glass Transition Temperature (K)'.

In my application I have a pandas dataframe with 1000s strings similar ro 'CCOCCO'.  I want to define a function that takes the pandas dataframe strings, put it in the search box in the above website and extract 'Glass Transition Temperature (K)'.

After I was unable to get what I want from beautifulsoup, the internet search is telling me selenium is the answer.  I started using it for this application but with no success. I really appreciate any help and directions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you enter **CCOCCO** in the search box and click on **Predict Propertie**, from the predicted table to extract the value of **Glass Transition Temperature (K)** you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = Options()
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
  options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\ChromeDriver\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')    
  driver.get('https://www.polymergenome.org/explore/index.php?m=1')       
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='large_input_no_round ui-autocomplete-input' and @id='keyword_original']"))).send_keys("CCOCCO")
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='dark_blue_button_no_round' and @value='Predict Properties']").click()
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@class='record']//tbody/tr[@class='record']//following::td[7]/center/font/font"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  206 ±       29
  ```

Comment: @DebanjanB-Thank you very much!

Comment: @DebanjanB-Thank again for your help.  I have a function (based on your solution) that accept an array of 'SMILES String' but it stops executing after returning 5 'Temperature' because the website says "Visits of more than 5 times per day to the property prediction capability requires login. "  Although i have created an account and checked the box 'remember my password', the website is giving an alarm.

Could you please modify your code to account for this exception; basically I would like selenium web driver to accept my user id/password so we don't get this error.  thanks in advance.

Comment: @A.E Can you please raise a new question as per your new requirement?

Comment: @DebanjanB- Sure, I will do

Comment: @DebanjanB- Here is my new post:            https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51887473/how-to-automate-login-credential-inside-a-loop-of-selenium-web-driver